# How to prevent session hijacking in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

In my website, there is a login form that saves a session variable using Asp.Net identity if the login succeeds.

How can I prevent session hijacking or session fixation (entering as other people's logins)?

My site is using HTTPS and Asp.NET web forms.